# Convert hex long to string in Java

Tags: java, type-conversion

I would like to know how to convert a hex long number to string l.
For example:
0x000104001L
How does it convert to “1064961”?

Comment: Hex is just a notation in source code. The number itself is just a number, there is nothing special about it that makes it a "hex number". You can convert it to a string just like any other number.

Comment: Did you check out the api docs for `java.lang.Long`? Also, the 'zero method' `"" + v`  will do it

Comment: I tried to convert and still dont understand how 0x000104001L becomes “1064961“. When I convert long to string it gives me a completely different number @Jesper

Comment: @Sonyagold, _"... When I convert long to string it gives me a completely different number ..."_, use the _[Long#toHexString](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Long.html#toHexString(long))_ method; `Long.toHexString(0x000104001L)`.  Or, if you additionally want the _0x_ prefix, and leading zeros, you can use _[String#formatted](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#formatted(java.lang.Object...))_, `"0x%09x".formatted(value)`.

Answer (score 3):

In 0x000104001L, the `0x` represents that this number has been written in hexadecimal notation. The `L` at the end represents that it is a `long` number. Similarly, if you see a number beginning with a `0`, it has been assigned to a variable in the octal notation. **For normal display, Java uses decimal notation.** That is why you see these numbers in decimal notation on your console.

**Demo:**

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long x = 0x000104001L;
        System.out.println(x);

        long y = 01245;
        System.out.println(y);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1064961
677
```

I hope you already know how to [convert a number from hexadecimal to a decimal notation](https://byjus.com/maths/hex-to-decimal/). So, (104001)<sub>16</sub> = (1 * 16<sup>5</sup> + 0 * 16<sup>4</sup> + 4 * 16<sup>3</sup> + 0 * 16<sup>2</sup> + 0 * 16<sup>1</sup> + 1 * 16<sup>0</sup>)<sub>10</sub> = (1048576 + 0 + 16384 + 0 + 0 + 1)<sub>10</sub> = (1064961)<sub>10</sub>.

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer in Java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = Long.toString(0x000104001L, 10);
    System.out.println(s);
}
```